# LEFT JOIN de dos campos en la misma tabla

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla de usuarios en los que tengo el user_id y el número de tarjeta tip. A la vez tengo otra tabla de informes llamada jef en la que un informe lo puede haber hecho un comercial o ambos, es decir, tiene dos campos "agente_1" y "agente_2" que almacenan el user_id de dicho agente. A la hora de hacer la consulta con LEFT JOIN no me deja hacerla a no ser que le ponga un solo LEFT JOIN:

```
$query= mysql_query("
SELECT agente_1, agente_2, u1.tip, u2.tip,
FROM jef
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS u1 ON jef.agente_1 = u1.user_id
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS u2 ON jef.agente_2 = u2.user_id
")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: He podido solucionarlo. Edito la pregunta con el resultado. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un alias para la segunda tabla

```
$query= mysql_query("select * from jef
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.user_id = jef.agente_1 
LEFT JOIN usuarios2 ON usuarios2.user_id = jef.agente_2
order by id_jef asc")or die(mysql_error());
```